# Need help to login oauth secured webapplication using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use record and playback to perform performance testing of OAuth-secured aplication. But I am not able to capture access token as it is getting generated with help of AWS Cognito.
I have also tried to use Selenium to login to web application, but Chrome is opening just for a sec and getting closed automatically without executing further code, and not even throwing any error.

I need help. How should I proceed with it?

I am using JMeter 5.5.
Thanks in advance.

1. Login using selenium - browser is getting closed in few seconds
2. try setting up AWS SDK for java

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a properly formed request to the [Authorize endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html). If you need to supply a `code_challenge` - it can be calculated using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

With regards to  " crome is opening just for a sec and getting closed automatically" - check request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and if it's empty - take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), you will see the error in at least one of these places.